# How to upload contacts CSV file to my Gmail account?

Tags: c#, google-data-protocol

Just wondering whether it' s possible to upload a CSV file with contacts information in it to my Gmail account?

I already looked at the Google Data API. it only allows you to add one at a time. Is there a bulk import ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, I found a method called `Batch` inside `ContactsRequest` class

```
               newContact.Title = name;
               newContact.Name.FullName = name;

               EMail primaryEmail = new EMail(email);
               primaryEmail.Primary = true;
               primaryEmail.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork;
               newContact.Emails.Add(primaryEmail);

               newContact.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData();
               newContact.BatchData.Id = i.ToString();
               newContact.BatchData.Type = GDataBatchOperationType.insert;
               i ++;
               list.Add(newContact);
```

And then

```
           cr.Batch(list, new Uri(f.AtomFeed.Batch), GDataBatchOperationType.insert);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: a picture that shows the very thing the question asks]

What are you asking exactly? GMail has it right there inside gmail. Must you do it from the data protocol ONLY?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the API then the answer's probably "no".  But it';s wouldn't be hard to write a script to parse the CSV file and call the API to import each contact in turn.